# MySql 8 syntax error when importing the database via phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I've a mysql database to import from mysql version 5 and when importing to MySql version 8. I get syntax error. I used a MySql syntax checker https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/ and it reported an error

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: '(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '
{vm:vendorname}
{vm:vendoraddress}

', `' at line 7
```

Below is my sql

```
CREATE TABLE `lcjg6_virtuemart_vendors_en_gb` (
  `virtuemart_vendor_id` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vendor_store_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `vendor_terms_of_service` text NOT NULL,
  `vendor_legal_info` text NOT NULL,
  `vendor_letter_css` text NOT NULL,
  `vendor_letter_header_html` longtext(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<h1>{vm:vendorname}</h1><p>{vm:vendoraddress}</p>',
  `vendor_letter_footer_html` longtext(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<p>{vm:vendorlegalinfo}<br />Page {vm:pagenum}/{vm:pagecount}</p>',
  `vendor_store_name` varchar(180) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vendor_phone` varchar(26) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vendor_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `metadesc` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `metakey` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `customtitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vendor_invoice_free1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vendor_invoice_free2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vendor_mail_free1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vendor_mail_free2` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vendor_mail_css` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(192) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`virtuemart_vendor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your longtext into varchar (because longtext doesnt support default value)
from this:

```
`vendor_letter_header_html` longtext(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<h1>{vm:vendorname}</h1><p>{vm:vendoraddress}</p>',
`vendor_letter_footer_html` longtext(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<p>{vm:vendorlegalinfo}<br />Page {vm:pagenum}/{vm:pagecount}</p>',
```

to this :

```
`vendor_letter_header_html` varchar(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<h1>{vm:vendorname}</h1><p>{vm:vendoraddress}</p>',
`vendor_letter_footer_html` varchar(8000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '<p>{vm:vendorlegalinfo}<br />Page {vm:pagenum}/{vm:pagecount}</p>',
```

You probably will get [row size limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html) error like this:

> 1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table
> type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead,
> check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

So either you reduce the length of that two column or make the default value being inserted by backend program. If you choose the later, make it longtext(without length):

```
`vendor_letter_header_html` longtext,
`vendor_letter_footer_html` longtext,
```

For further understanding, refer to mysql [char & varchar types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) and [blob & text types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html).